# A surface containing all polynomial curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Consider  a surface S  in three dimensions, such that  for any  polynomial function  P there exists a real Z so that the intersection of the plane z=Z and S  is P.; also every curve obtsined by intersection of S with a plane parelell  to xy plane is a polynomial.

What is the  equation/description of S

Comment: A surface is 2-dimensional. So are you talking about a surface or a 3-dimensional variety?

Comment: No I am talking of a surface in 3 dim spsce. Thanks

Comment: "the intersection of the plane z=Z and S is P": how can it be a polynomial function? It's a subset of S. Do you mean that this intersection is the vanishing locus of P?

Comment: In the curve obtained on the plane z=Z upon intersection with S; y varies  as a polynomial function of x.

Comment: How do you know that S exists? I think you are asking for too much here, maybe you could restrict to polynomials of a fixed degree $d$ first (or some other sort of restriction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\alpha_n : [n-1, n] \to [-n, n]^n$ be a continuous space-filling curve that fills an $n$-dimensional cube of side length $2n$, starting and ending at its midpoint.

Combine these $\alpha_n$ into a single continuous surjective curve $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \to \oplus_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb{R}$ by setting

$$\alpha(z) = \begin{cases}0 &\text{if}& z \leq 0 \\ \alpha_n(z) &\text{if}& z \in [n-1, n], n \in \mathbb{N}.\end{cases}$$

Now let $P : \oplus_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}[X]$ be the linear bijection defined by $P(a) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty{a_iX^i}$.

We see that the map $\Phi := P \circ \alpha$ is a surjective continuous curve over the space of all real polynomials.

Now define $S = \{(x, \Phi(z)(x), z) : (x, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. This set is topologically a surface, since it is the graph of a continuous function $\Phi(.)(.) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, and it satisfies the properties you have given, namely that each horizontal slice is the graph of the polynomial function $\Phi(z)$, and since $\Phi$ is surjective, any polynomial function has a corresponding slice in $S$.

Note also that $S$ is rather crooked and definitely not differentiable, at least for $z > 0$.